# How to restore div which is hidden using empty() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
html code:
<button id="add"></button>    
<div id="count_search">
        <span class="total_count">Total: <span id="record_count"></span></span></span>
        <input type="text" class="txtbox search" placeholder="Search" id="search">
    </div>
Jquery code:
$("#add").click(function(){
       $("#count_search").empty();
})
```

I want to show count_search div once again on clicking on any other button execpt to add button
In above code add is button on which empty() is implimented. On clicking on add button count_search is got hide. Then after I want to restore that div content

Answer (score 1):

`.empty()` deletes the elements in your container (count_search).
Instead, you can use `.hide()/.show()` or better approach, you can use `.toggle()` that show or hide your element.

```js
$("#add2").click(function() {
    $("#count_search").toggle();
});
$("#add").click(function() {

    if ($("#count_search").is(":visible")) {
        $("#count_search").hide();
    } else {
        $("#count_search").show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Show/Hide</button>    
<button id="add2">Toggle</button>    
<div id="count_search">
   <span class="total_count">Total: <span id="record_count"></span></span></span>
   <input type="text" class="txtbox search" placeholder="Search" id="search">
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a good practice, if you need to change something in the future, or another programmer, would need to review your entire code to understand what you did. Add the elements in your html directly and use jQuery to hide or show them based on your needs. And with CSS you can add classes instead of adding styles inline.

Answer (score 0):

By **empty()** you are deleting an item in DOM.

 Instead of empty, you can use **toggle()**, which hides the element and If you click once again, the item will show.

```
$("#add").click(function(){
       $("#count_search").hide();
})
```

Comment: I don't want to show this on clicking on add button. I want to show this on clicking on different button except to add button.

Comment: Okay, than use hide() function.

Comment: update my answer.